# How to get members of Root Site and Communication Site with Graph API

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I could get members of Site base on the Group (`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members`). But I could not get the members of Root Site and Communication Site because these sites have not belong to any Group.

Is there any way to get members of the Root Site and Communication Site with Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Duplicate on SharePoint stackexchange : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/281160/67794

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dam,

You will need to use SharePoint Rest API instead of Graph API.
As in SharePoint site, there is no Office 365 Group inside site.

Rest API Endpoint:

```
_api/Web/SiteGroups/GetByName('SiteName Members')/users
```

Reference:

[REST API - Retrieve Group Members](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264090/rest-api-retrieve-group-members)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems i need to change the new approach.